# Unable to create new directories or mysql table as root - quota error?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization, quota, inode

I recently updated an ubuntu 14 box to version 16.04. Everything appeared to go smoothly, however now I am unable to create any new mysql tables.

I'm signed into the ubuntu box as root and mysql as the root user. The error I receive when trying to create any table is:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'foo' (errno: 122)
```

I've done some investigation and I'm lead to believe this is a disk quota error. As much as I understand mysql and some basic webserver bits, I'm not an expert in general ubuntu administration. I've run `quota` and it returns

```
Disk quotas for user root (uid 0): none
```

Is anyone able to advise what I need to do here to fix this? Thanks

Based on a comment I checked my syslog and I see

```
../../../../lib/isc/unix/file.c:347: unexpected error:
 unable to convert errno to isc_result: 122: Disk quota exceeded
 dumping master file: tmp-jaCquXzkj6: open: unexpected error
 CRON[32105]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
 CRON[32104]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
```

***update***
this happened even when creating a simple table such as

```
  create table foo(id int);
```

But I've also noticed I get a quota error just trying to create a dir e.g

```
  mkdir test

  mkdir: cannot create directory 'test': Disk quota exceeded
```

I ran the `df` command and I get the following output

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs       50000000 6390516  43609484  13% /
devtmpfs         1048576       0   1048576   0% /dev
tmpfs            1048576       0   1048576   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1048576  102008    946568  10% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1048576       0   1048576   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             1048576       0   1048576   0% /run/shm
tmpfs             209716       0    209716   0% /run/user/0
```

df -hi shows

```
df -hi
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs        245K  245K     0  100% /
devtmpfs         256K    56  256K    1% /dev
tmpfs            256K     1  256K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            256K   411  256K    1% /run
tmpfs            256K     7  256K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            256K    10  256K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             256K     1  256K    1% /run/shm
tmpfs            256K     4  256K    1% /run/user/0
```

and quota -v

```
Disk quotas for user root (uid 0): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/vzfs 5781580       0       0          218669       0       0
```

I then deleted one tar.gz file and now `df -i`shows

Filesystem                   Inodes                IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on

```
/dev/vzfs      18446744069926773888 18446744069414834326 511939562  100% /
devtmpfs                     262144                   56    262088    1% /dev
tmpfs                        262144                    1    262143    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        262144                  410    261734    1% /run
tmpfs                        262144                    7    262137    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        262144                   10    262134    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                         262144                    1    262143    1% /run/shm
tmpfs                        262144                    4    262140    1% /run/user/0
```

Can anyone explain what's going on and how can I fix this. The machine has plenty of space left, but for some reason the quota is full and I don't know enough about inodes to know how to resolve this and stop myself from hitting this error in the future (physical disk space permitting)

*** EDIT 2 ***
Ok so after digging around I've managed to find this command `du --inodes -d 3 / | sort -n | tail`

which shows the following results

```
13136   /usr/lib
20145   /proc
26549   /usr/local/lib
29989   /usr/share
30239   /usr/local
78892   /usr
127929  /var/log/samba
128235  /var/log
145269  /var
259479  /
```

samba seems to be using a lot of space, but does anything else look out of the ordinary? I've removed a large number of node websites where node_modules where obviously using a fair amount of space but it's still not enough. I'm wondering if the update has resulted in a lot of redundant old packages, though apt-get remove hasn't cleared too much up.

I've changed my samba log rotation from weekly to daily so hopefully that will help

Comment: `df -hi` shows clearly that you are out of inodes. You need to delete files from the root filesystem.

Comment: This is what I'm not sure on though. I've read that zfs should increase the inodes in relation to disk space. I have plenty of disk space left so why the limit on inodes?

Comment: you can not increase inode limit straight forward. You have to delete some files for this issue. It seems you are having many files with small size. so find out such files with very small size and delete it.

Comment: you have a lot of very small or 0 sized files somewhere you need to find and delete

Comment: I realise that and using some of the commands above, I've located and deleted loads of files to free up 55% of space. However this is obviously a reactive process and perhaps some ideas to help identify the issue and resolve at source might be useful